# Program works in a subfolder in vscode but not if only the folder is opened

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, subdirectory

The problem is that i have a small program that works in itself. I'm using vscode.
This programm is currently located in a subfolder of the folder that i have opened.

However, if i go to File>Open Folder and select the subfolder with the program as the new main folder from which I work, nothing seems to work anymore. The program itself doesn't even start to run, no text is coloured, etc.
Does someone know the reason for this?

Comment: you have to provide your code , your file/folder structure and your error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the subfolder as a new workspace, you will

1. lose the `settings.json` under `.vscode` folder
2. the `cwd` will be changed
3. the virtual environment under the previous folder will lose

and so on.

So you need the follow the error message to fix the problem. If you can provide the error message and the screenshot, maybe we can provide some help.

But no text is colored, it's weird, have you selected the `Dark(visual studio)` theme?